# What's the difference between VarDeclaredNames and VarScopedDeclarations?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecma262

I'm reading EcmaScript specification.

At 9.2.12, there are:

```
11.Let varNames be the VarDeclaredNames of code. 
12.Let varDeclarations be the VarScopedDeclarations of code.
```

And at 13.1.5 and 13.1.6:

```
13.1.5 Static Semantics: VarDeclaredNames

Statement :

EmptyStatement
ExpressionStatement
ContinueStatement
BreakStatement
ReturnStatement
ThrowStatement
DebuggerStatement
Return a new empty List.

13.1.6 Static Semantics: VarScopedDeclarations

Statement :

EmptyStatement
ExpressionStatement
ContinueStatement
BreakStatement
ReturnStatement
ThrowStatement
DebuggerStatement
Return a new empty List.
```

They look like the same.So I want to know what's the difference between `VarDeclaredNames` and `VarScopedDeclarations` ? Can you give me some examples?

Thanks.

Comment: §13.1 is not the only section detailing these static semantics

Comment: @Bergi sorry,I know there are "See also: 13.1.5, 13.2.11, 13.3.2.2, 13.6.5, 13.7.2.4, 13.7.3.4, 13.7.4.5, 13.7.5.7, 13.11.5, 13.12.7, 13.13.12, 13.15.5, 14.2.12, 15.1.5, 15.2.1.13". But I don't find any other explanation describles the problem more detailedly than 13.1

Comment: Well, in those sections for the other kinds of statements the `VarDeclaredNames` differ from the `VarScopedDeclarations`.

Comment: They return different data types, so that seems like a big difference?

Comment: @Bergi I checked all other kinds of statements  in those sections, they are really the same

Comment: @loganfsmyth Really?Can you tell me what you say in which section?Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those two static semantic rules search the AST for the same kinds of things: *VariableDeclaration*s, *ForBinding*s, *FunctionDeclaration*s and *GeneratorDeclaration*s. There's a lot of duplication (especially in methodology) indeed.

However, as @loganfsmyth mentions in the comments, they do return different data - different types of lists. While `VarDeclaredNames` returns a list of names (strings), `VarScopedDeclarations` does return a list of declarations (i.e. AST nodes).

This is apparent in the sections where something is actually appended to the lists: [§13.3.2.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-variable-statement-static-semantics-vardeclarednames), [§13.7.4.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-statement-static-semantics-vardeclarednames), [§13.7.5.7](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements-static-semantics-vardeclarednames), and [§13.2.9](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-block-static-semantics-toplevelvardeclarednames) all do refer to the `BoundNames` of the respective element, while [§13.3.2.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-variable-statement-static-semantics-varscopeddeclarations), [§13.7.4.6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-statement-static-semantics-varscopeddeclarations), [§13.7.5.8](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements-static-semantics-varscopeddeclarations), and [§13.2.10](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-block-static-semantics-toplevelvarscopeddeclarations) do refer to the respective declaration itself.

Why is this distinction needed? The `VarDeclaredNames` are used to create the bindings in the scope, while the `VarScopedDeclarations` are used to find the function declarations to create (and initialise the bindings with those values).

Could it have been simpler? Yes, surely - for lexical declarations, the [scope initialisation description](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-block-static-semantics-toplevelvardeclarednames) just iterates the declarations and gets the `BoundNames` of each. <s>You might want to submit a bug to spec authors to use this approach for function-level declarations as well.</s> See [issue 1203](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/1203) discussing this.

Comment: thanks for your answer! By the way, can you give me some suggestions on reading the spec?Because sometimes there are a few terms or discriptions that I can't understand. Thanks again! @Bergi