# ECMAScript: Is VarScopedDeclarations not returning FunctionDeclaration?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

My question is with regards to the [ECMAScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262).

I am currently following the specification to understand how a simple script is evaluated from start to end.

[Following on from this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74758029/ecmascript-functiondeclaration-statement-returning-empty/74758391#74758391), I am walking through the [GlobalDeclarationInstantiation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-globaldeclarationinstantiation) to see how a *FunctionDeclaration* gets instantiated (identifier added to the *Global Environment Record* (GER)) and initialized (value added to the identifier in the GER).

That leads me to step 5 of [GlobalDeclarationInstantiation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-globaldeclarationinstantiation): `Let varDeclarations be the VarScopedDeclarations of script.`.

Looking at [VarScopedDeclarations](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-static-semantics-varscopeddeclarations), it seems to me that it never returns a Parse Node for  *FunctionDeclaration*. In fact, it returns empty Lists for all syntactic grammar symbols, except for *VarDeclarations*. Which means that it only returns Parse Nodes for symbols following the **var** keyword. [VarScopedDeclarations](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-static-semantics-varscopeddeclarations) of `var a = 5` would return a Parse Node containing `a = 5`.

**Questions**

1. Does [VarScopedDeclarations](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-static-semantics-varscopeddeclarations) ever return a Parse Node for *FunctionDeclaration*?
2. If it does not, will step 8.1.i (`i. Assert: d is either a FunctionDeclaration...`) ever be a positive assertion?
3. If [VarScopedDeclarations](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-static-semantics-varscopeddeclarations) returns empty lists for most symbols, why have the spec creators bothered including them? Would it not be cleaner to only include the ones that actually return a Parse Node entry? It is the same in [LexicallyScopedDeclarations](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-static-semantics-lexicallyscopeddeclarations) and a few other operations.

Comment: Oh they changed this, [previously (ES6) it was spread out all over the spec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40623284/1048572)… Nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Looking at [VarScopedDeclarations](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-static-semantics-varscopeddeclarations), it seems to me that it never returns a Parse Node for  *FunctionDeclaration*. In fact, it returns empty Lists for all syntactic grammar symbols, except for *VarDeclarations*.

I think you missed a few bits there:

```
FunctionStatementList : StatementList
  1. Return the TopLevelVarScopedDeclarations of StatementList.

ClassStaticBlockStatementList : StatementList
  1. Return the TopLevelVarScopedDeclarations of StatementList.

ScriptBody : StatementList
  1. Return TopLevelVarScopedDeclarations of StatementList.
```

And then [TopLevelVarScopedDeclarations](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-static-semantics-toplevelvarscopeddeclarations) does indeed return what you expected, the function declarations that should be hoisted:

```
StatementListItem : Declaration
  1. If Declaration is Declaration : HoistableDeclaration , then
    a. Let declaration be DeclarationPart of HoistableDeclaration.
    b. Return « declaration ».
  2. Return a new empty List.

LabelledItem : FunctionDeclaration
  1. Return « FunctionDeclaration ».
```

(where a [HoistableDeclaration](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-HoistableDeclaration) is any of `FunctionDeclaration`, `GeneratorDeclaration`, `AsyncFunctionDeclaration`, `AsyncGeneratorDeclaration`)

---

You may have been confused by [VarScopedDeclarations](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-static-semantics-varscopeddeclarations)' rule

```
StatementListItem : Declaration
  1. Return a new empty List.
```

Yes, this does return no function declarations, but this rule applies only to *StatementListItem*s inside a *Block* or *CaseBlock*. VarScopedDeclarations does recurse into blocks, but only to find *VariableDeclaration*s in there, not to find function declarations - they do not hoist out of blocks.

Comment: Thanks! On your last point: I might be reading the grammar wrong, but it seems to me that *StatementListItem* can occur inside *StatementList* (clause 14.2 Block), and *StatementList* can occur in a wide range of different places (not just within a *Block*). As such, how are you able to conclude that the *StatementListItem* mentioned in * VarScopedDeclarations* is referring to a *StatementListItem* within a *Block*?

Comment: @Magnus Ah, good call, I jumped to the conclusion too early. But it's actually not that a wide range of different places - there's only *Block*, *CaseBlock*, *FunctionStatementList*, *ClassStaticBlockStatementList* and *ScriptBody*. And the last three explicitly delegate to `TopLevelVarScopedDeclarations` which doesn't recurse. Tbh, I think the recursion would be cleaner (and easier to understand) if the respective `…DeclarationInstantiation` algorithms would directly call `TopLevelVarScopedDeclarations`, which then would delegate to a recursive `InnerVarScopedDeclarations` operation.

Comment: Indeed, @Bergi. Is this a conflict in *VarScopedDeclarations*: *StatementListItem* can occur in *StatementList*, which can occur in *FunctionStatementList*. Thus, a *Declaration* (eg *FunctionDeclaration*) in a *FunctionStatementList* should return an empty list. However, further down in *VarScopedDeclarations* it says: `FunctionStatementList : StatementList -> Return "FunctionDeclaration"` (through *TopLevelVarScopedDeclarations*). Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: "*Thus, a* Declaration *in a* FunctionStatementList *should return an empty list*" - only if you were to call `VarScopedDeclarations` directly on the *StatementList* of the function. But that doesn't happen, `VarScopedDeclarations` is called on the *FunctionStatementList*, and the rule for that makes it return the declarations (via `TopLevelVarScopedDeclarations`).

Comment: Not sure if you got a notification, but I made a room with a couple of follow-up questions, if/when you have time. Perhaps valuable for others too. Link: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250378/room-for-magnus-and-bergi